# How to serve always the same image?

Tags: tornado

I have url pattern:

```
static_path = '/home/user/statics/'
(r'/media/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': static_path}),
```

but I want to serve always only one image regardless of what is in /media/*

How to do it?

Comment: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.static_url

Comment: Sub class a handler and do your stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the group match the empty string, then it only serves the path provided:

```
(r'/media/.*()', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': '/home/www/image.jpg'})
```